# Correct Units for a 3D Vector

Tags: vectors, classical-mechanics, unit-of-measure

Given the units for the magnitude of a vector describing a force in a three dimensional context could be (N), is it correct to say the units of the vector iteself are also (N)? Should a distinction be made in the units of the vector's magnitude and the vector iteslf? Thanks

Comment: Just put the units in when using the equation for the magnitude of a vector and you will see that the magnitude and vector components must have the same units

Comment: Of course, Thankyou

Comment: Certainly ${}{}{}{}$